# Give an example of a language $L$ such that $|L| = 5$ and $|L^2| = 16$.

Tags: formal-languages

Can a formal language $L$ have identical string in it? For example, $L =\{a, a, b, c, b, d\}$. Is $L$ valid, if yes then is $|L|= 6$ or $|L| = 4$?

Comment: How is $L^2$ defined?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel $L^2$ is $L\cdot L$, i.e., the language of concatenated strings where the first and second both belong to $L$.

Comment: And no, languages are sets, so no duplicate elements.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: What are the empty squares in the title?

Comment: [Here's what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNY5u.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the language $L=\{a,aa,aaa,aaaa,b\}$. $$L^2=\{aa,aaa,aaaa,aaaaa,aaaaaa,aaaaaaa,aaaaaaaa,ab,ba,aab,baa,aaab,baaa,aaaab,baaaa,bb\}$$